# GUIDE4YOU/OL3 - how to read custom attributes of a layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, guide4you

How can I read custom attributes of a layer?

For example I've added a layer with custom attribute **test** and value **sam**.

[Console log map layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGeXO.jpg)

`createG4U('#g4u-map', 'conf/client.commented.json', 'conf/layers.commented.json').then(function (map) {
    map.asSoonAs('ready', true, function () {
        map.get('api').addFeatureLayer({
          "id": "1",
          "type": "GeoJSON",
          "style": stylefunction,
          "source": {
            "url": "files/sample.json"
          },
          "visible": true,
          "test" : "sam"
        });
        map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
            console.log(layer);
        });
    });
});`

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with `layer.get('test')`.

you won't get the layer with `getLayers()`, as the layers are nested in different layergroups.

the method `addFeatureLayer` will return a reference to the layer. You can save it and use it later.

Or you can use `recursiveForEach` which will iterate recursively through all nested layers.

You can either do it for all layers in the map with `map.getLayerGroup().recursiveForEach(function (layer) { ... })` or you can do it for featureLayers or baseLayers only with `map.get('featureLayers').recursiveForEach(function (layer) { ... })`

Comment: Not working, I get always 'undefined'. Even reading out attribute id (mandatory attribute) is 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks Simon!!**

Working code:

`createG4U('#g4u-map', 'conf/client.commented.json', 'conf/layers.commented.json').then(function (map) {
    map.asSoonAs('ready', true, function () {
        map.get('api').addFeatureLayer({
          "id": "1",
          "type": "GeoJSON",
          "style": stylefunction,
          "source": {
            "url": "files/sample.json"
          },
          "visible": true,
          "test" : "sam"
        });
        map.get('featureLayers').recursiveForEach(function (layer) {
            console.log(layer.get('test'));
        });
        //Make the layer visible in the menu
        map.get('UIConfigurator').configureUI();
    });
});`